# Rails 5 API passing a controller varible to the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to create a column in one of my models that uses the requesting user's id to generate the column. I get the current user from the request header:

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

if request.headers['Authorization']
  token_string = request.headers['Authorization']
  current_user = User.where(token: token_string).take
end
```

I create a method in the model that uses `current_user`:

```
# app/models/post.rb

attr_accessor :user_voted

def user_voted(current_user)
  if current_user
    return PostVote.where(post_id: self[:id], user_id: current_user[:id]).size > 0
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Before rendering in the controller I do:

```
@articles = Article.where(safe_params)
      .order(order)
      .limit(10)
      .offset(offset)

@articles.user_voted current_user
```

I get the following error when I try to run this:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `user_voted' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000003b8fbe8>):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:55:in `index'
```

What is the proper way to pass controller information to the model?

Comment: You are calling `user_voted` on a query result class `Post::ActiveRecord_Relation`.

Answer (score 0):

`@articles` is an instance of `Post::ActiveRecord_Relation`, and not an instance of `Post`. So you have to incorporate the `current_user` into your `where` clause in the controller.

```
@articles = Article.where(safe_params)
                   .order(order)
                   .limit(10)
                   .offset(offset)

@did_user_vote = @articles.joins(:post_votes)
                          .where(post_votes: { user_id: current_user.id })
                          .exists?
```

So you join the `post_votes` relation in your `@articles` query, and look for posts that have `PostVotes` for that user.

Comment: This produces an `INNER JOIN`, so I only get posts `current_user` voted for. I want all posts with a column indicating if the user voted for the post or not.

Comment: @JoshM. I'm afraid that's not possible. `ActiveRecord` does not know to what attribute it has to put that sudden "extra column" in. But why do you need that in a column? Why not just create a method in `Post.rb`

Comment: As mentioned in the question I do have a method in Post.rb, but I'm unable to reference the method from the controller, I get an error. A method in the model that looks if `current_user` voted does seem like the way to go.

Comment: @JoshM. but you're not calling `user_voted` on a `Post` class. You're calling `user_voted` on an `ActiveRecord_Relation` class. That class is used for collections returned from the database, not a single `Post` instance.